# How do I run puppeteer on a server/in the cloud

Tags: node.js, cloud, puppeteer

Feels like I've searched the entire web for an answer...to no avail. I have a puppeteer script that works perfectly locally. My local machine is a little unreliable, so I've been trying to push this script to the cloud so that it can run there. But I have no idea where to start. I'm sitting here with an IBM cloud account with no idea what to do. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Running Puppeteer scripts can be done on any cloud platform that

1. exposes a Node.js environment
2. enables running a browser (Puppeteer will need to start Chromium)
   This could be achieved, for example, using AWS EC2.

AWS Lambda, Google Cloud Functions and IBM Cloud Functions (and similar services) might also work but they might need additional work on your side to get the browser running.

For a step-by-step guide, I would suggest checking out [this article](https://medium.com/mockingbot/run-puppeteer-chrome-headless-on-ec2-amazon-linux-ami-6c9c6a17bee6) and [this follow-up.](https://medium.com/@kerion7/run-puppeteer-chrome-headless-on-ec2-amazon-linux-ami-e63280d4f0f5)

Also, it might just be easier to look into services like Checkly (*disclaimer: I work for Checkly*), Browserless and similar (a quick search for something along the lines of "run puppeteer online" will return several of those), which allow you to run Puppeteer checks online without requiring any additional setup. Useful if you are serious about using Puppeteer for testing or synthetic monitoring in the long run.

Comment: Because links to external sites might become dead at one point, it's better to summarise the info in your answer, while retaining the link to the original post for more detailed instructions, as well as for attribution

Comment: Does it work with nodechef?